# Excel 2013 cannot find and open the file in ThisWorkbook directory

Tags: vba, excel

The following issue occured to me. I use MS Excel 2013.

With the macro below I tried to find those accounts (which meets the criteria "In scope", e.g. account 12345678), to copy them, to search in the same folder (where ThisWorkbook is), to find another excel file which has as name the number of account (e.g. "12345678.xlsx") and to open it.

After the proposed corrections below, my macro finds and opens the desired file. But now the problem is that no actions can be performed on it: copy, paste, etc.

Could you please help on this?

```
Sub FileFinder()

'Excel variables:
Dim RngS As Excel.Range
Dim wbResults As Workbook

'Go to the column with specific text
Worksheets("Accounts source data").Activate
X = 3
Y = 25
While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Accounts source data").Cells(X, Y))
    Sheets("Accounts source data").Cells(X, Y).Select
    If ActiveCell = "In scope" Then
        Sheets("Accounts source data").Cells(X, Y - 22).Select
        'Copy the account in scope
        Set RngS = Selection
        Selection.Copy
        'Search, in same directory where the file is located, the file with that account (file comes with account number as name)

        sDir = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & RngS & ".xlsx", vbNormal)
        Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sDir)
        'Here is where my error occurs 
        '[Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument]
        Sheet2.Cells("B27:B30").Copy
        oWB.Close
        End If
    X = X + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: most likely you are missing the "\" seperator between `ThisWorkbook.Path` and the File name

Comment: What @ShaiRado said. Once you resolve that: `Sheets()` implicitly references the `ActiveWorkbook`. The moment you execute `Workbooks.Open` the newly opened workbook becomes the `ActiveWorkbook`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1576/common-mistakes/5110/qualifying-references) for more info. You can also avoid a lot of the issues by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate). Read quickly, sadly documentation is going away.

Comment: @FreeMan - I know my coding is not as elegant as it should but I am beginner in VBA. The improvements will come next for sure! Thanks! ;)

Comment: @FreeMan note that [SO is sunsetting documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation); these links will eventually die ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - hence _Read quickly, sadly documentation is going away._ :)

Comment: @FreeMan [archived!](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809140122/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201708091401221764826)

Comment: @Shai Rado - I did what you porposed but now another issue appeared (plese refer to the updated post of mine, review and advise on it)

Comment: @VSE see my answer and code below (I have some questions for you, they are in the code as comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, I have my explanation and questions for you in the code (as commnets):

```
Option Explicit

Sub FileFinder()

' Excel variables:
Dim wbResults As Workbook
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim RngS As Range
Dim sDir As String

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, Col As Long

Col = 25

' set ThisWorkbook object
Set wbResults = ThisWorkbook

' set the worksheet object
Set Sht = Worksheets("Accounts source data")
With Sht
    ' find last row with data in Column "Y" (Col = 25)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, Col) = "In scope" Then
            ' Set the range directly, no need to use `Select` and `Selection`
            Set RngS = .Cells(i, Col).Offset(, -22)

            ' Search, in same directory where the file is located, the file with that account (file comes with account number as name)
            sDir = Dir$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & RngS.Value & ".xlsx", vbNormal)
            Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sDir)

            oWB.Worksheets("Report").Range("B27:B30").Copy

            ' *** Paste in ThisWorkbook, in my exmaple "Sheet2" <-- modify to your needs
            wbResults.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

            oWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
'            sDir = Dir$

            ' clear objects
            Set RngS = Nothing
            Set oWB = Nothing
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: About Sheet2 - It is the Sheet2 (Report), according to the VBA Project Objects, in the new opened file which the coding tried to find in the same directory. 
About pasting - once I copy the cells from the new opend file, I want to go back to ThisWorkbook, where the macro is located, and to paste the selection in another sheet within the initial excel file (ThisWorkbook).
About the "Loop" & "sDir = Dir$" - sorry, I didn't erase it. It left in the code from my previous tries. Please ignore it!

Comment: @VSE so what happens when you try the edoted code ? (just edited it)

Comment: @ Shai Rado - when I run the code, you proposed, this message appears: Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438).

Comment: @VSE without telling me at what line are you getting this error, there is almost nothing I can do

Comment: @ Shai Rado  "oWB.Sheet2.Range("B27:B30").Copy' - after it is read

Comment: @VSE  but this code doesn't exist anymore, see edited code

Comment: @ Shai Rado - After revising your solution it works but now I cannot go back to the initial file (ThisWorkbook) and to paste the copied cells as transposed values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151578/discussion-between-vse-and-shai-rado).

Comment: @VSE see edited code, let me know if you need further help (I think I halped you with your post, now it's "extras" )

Comment: I agrre with you totlly that there are some ad hoc/extra doubts. I accep your solution fully. Bu final question related to 'Range("C1")" where I am pasting the selected - if I want to keep the same row where the macro stoped (and execute the steps for searching file, finding file, coping cells) but to go to Column N (or  Offset(,-11) - how to persorm that action?

Comment: @VSE  open a new post, add our latest code, and describe what is not working, and me (and others) will gladly assist